# Azure Synapse Copy Activity error: CREATE TABLE dbo is not supported

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am having trouble using the Table Option named **Auto Create Table** on a Copy Data activity.
The source I use is a REST API which can be requested correctly, and actually data can be previewed normally.
However, **even though I count with every permission available (including blob storage contributor), the following message is received after Debug given the settings of Sink section of Copy Data:**

*{

"errorCode": "2200",

"message": "ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A database operation failed with the following error: 'CREATE TABLE dbo is not supported.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=CREATE TABLE dbo is not supported.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider,SqlErrorNumber=15868,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=5,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=15868,State=5,Message=CREATE TABLE dbo is not supported.,},],'",

"failureType": "UserError",

"target": "From API to Data Lake",

"details": []

}*

**Below I attach screenshots of the Copy Data settings. I use Azure SQL Database as our Sink dataset, and the same for Linked Service. Even though we create a table beforehand, the process does not work. Given that I wish to use the Serverless SQL pool, are there any suggestions or alternatives for this pipeline to work properly?**

[Azure Synapse copy data config1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5c5P.png)

[Azure Synapse copy data config2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PX14U.png)

I am trying to make a GET Request to the API I am working with, and to send the data from the generated parquet file to a table using the Copy Data activity, using Azure SQL Database as Sink dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried to reproduce your scenario and I got similar error.**

[image]

The Cause as per [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/on-demand-workspace-overview#t-sql-support)

> The Serverless SQL pool has no local storage, only metadata objects are stored in databases. Therefore, T-SQL related to the following concepts isn't supported:
>
> > - Tables
> > - Triggers
> > - Materialized views
> > - DDL statements other than ones related to views and security
> > - DML statements

> **Given that I wish to use the Serverless SQL pool, are there any suggestions or alternatives for this pipeline to work properly?**

As we can not create table in Serverless SQL, but we can create external table in serverless SQL.
The workaround is to store the data from API in the `ADLS`  of the synapse workspace as csv file and then create external table on it as below:

- Storing the API data in the `ADLS`  of the synapse workspace as csv file
  [image]
- Then Go to synapse workspace And **Data >> Linked >> select your ADLS account and container >> click on file >> New SQL script >> Create External Table.**
  [image]
- Check all settings and click on continue.
  [image]
- Give the table name you want and click on Open script it will generate the script.
  [image]
- Run the script

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please check if 'dbo' schema exist or not in the database. If it doesn't exist you can create it by using the following query in precopy script of sink settings.

`IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.schemas WHERE name = 'dbo') BEGIN EXEC sp_executesql N'CREATE SCHEMA dbo'; END`

Comment: not synapse related